# print data from mysql into a pdf file using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I am using FPDF for the PDF and so far in my search I saw this similar question to my question and followed the code there and when I ran it no Error was being called and the PDf can be downloaded. But the problem is when I open the PDF file it is empty and I can't seem to understand the problem. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include("connections.php");
require("fpdf181/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF(); 
$name = $address = $email = "";
$nameErr = $addressErr = $emailErr = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ 
if(empty($_POST["name"])){
    $nameErr = "Name is required!";
}else{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}
if(empty($_POST["address"])){
    $addressErr = "Address is required!";
}else{
    $address = $_POST["address"];
}
if(empty($_POST["email"])){
    $emailErr = "Email is required!";
}else{
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}   
}
//When button is clicked the pdf will be generated
if (isset($_POST["btn_1"])) {
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('','',12);

$view_query = mysqli_query($connections, "SELECT * FROM sample");
//where the database is accessed
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($view_query))
{
$db_name = $row["Name"];
$db_address = $row["Address"];
$db_email = $row["Email"];

$pdf->Cell(0,10,'', $db_name,1); 
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'', $db_address,1); 
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'', $db_email,1); 
$pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();

}
?>
<style>
.error{
color:red;  
}
</style>

<form method = "POST" action= "<?php htmlspecialchars("PHP_SELF");?>">

<input type = "text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><br>
<span class = "error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br>

<input type = "text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"><br>
<span class = "error"><?php echo $addressErr;?></span><br>

<input type = "text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"><br>
<span class = "error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br>

<input type = "submit" value="Submit">

<input type = "submit" name="btn_1" value="PDF">

</form>

<?php
// Insert to table
if($name && $address && $email){
$query = mysqli_query($connections, "INSERT INTO sample(Name,Address,Email) 
VALUES('$name','$address','$email')");

echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('New Record has been inserted!')
</script>";
echo"<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
}
//view table
$view_query = mysqli_query($connections, "SELECT * FROM sample");
echo"<table border = '1' width ='50%'>";
echo "<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Address</td>
<td>Email</td>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($view_query)) {

$db_name = $row["Name"];
$db_address = $row["Address"];
$db_email = $row["Email"];
echo "<tr>
<td>$db_name</td>
<td>$db_address</td>
<td>$db_email</td>
</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($connections);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
$pdf->SetFont('','',12);
```

sets your font to **current font**.

But you didn't set any font earlier, so fpdf doesn't know, which font to use.

So, **first**, you need to set font as described in [SetFont manual page](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm).

Next, is [Cell](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) function. It's definition is

```
Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])
```

See? Text which you want to write to pdf comes as **third** parameter.

In you call

```
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'', $db_name,1);
```

**third** parameter is what? Empty string, I suppose.

So, second, you need to fix your `Cell` calls.

Comment: Thanks I will try that out sir!

Comment: It works thank you sir! Sorry if I look a newbie which is actually true hehe, just started studying PHP and SQL. Thank you so much sir :)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this also:

```
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF 
      In PHP");
      $pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
      $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
      $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
      $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
      $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
      $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
      $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
      $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
      $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);
      $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);
      $pdf->AddPage();
```